# desgin bloger system database sechema with mongoDB (noSQL)

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database, nosql

This is my table structure:

website has many users

each user has many weblogs

each weblog has many articles

each article has many comments,

whats is best design for it in mongoDB?

is it true?

```
{ 
    user:[
        {name:"john",
            weblog : [
                { name: "new blog",
                    article : [
                        {
                            title: "this is first article",
                            comment  :[
                                   {text": comment },
                                   {...comment...},
                                   {...comment...}
                            ]
                        }
                        {...article...},
                        {...article...}

                    ]
                }
                {...weblog...},
                {...weblog...},
                {...weblog...}
            ],
        },
        { ...user... },
        { ...user... },
        { ...user... }
    ]

}
```

Is it standard?

I think it is too nested. is it noraml for search?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is help me.

http://openmymind.net/Multiple-Collections-Versus-Embedded-Documents/#11

hope help someone else...

finaly I choose seprate ducuments...